# El webservice para consutla de facturas de AFIP (en producción) devuelve "SoapFault exception: Could not connect to host"

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

No puedo consumir el servicio ws_sr_padron_a4 de afip en producción... en homologación anda bien.

Estoy usando los ejemplos de afip que se encuentran en http://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/ y el wsdl que estoy usando en produccion es https://aws.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4?WSDL (los datos del servicio están en http://afip.gob.ar/ws/ws_sr_padron_a4/manual_ws_sr_padron_a4_v1.1.pdf)

Me devuelve

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not
>   connect to host

Comment: si no mostrar como lo estas consumiendo o mostras algo de codigo nadie te podra ayudar

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, el wsdl de afip tenía un error... (https://aws.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4?WSDL)

En la parte de abajo del wsdl:

```html
<wsdl:service name="PersonaServiceA4">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PersonaServiceA4SoapBinding" name="PersonaServiceA4Port">
      <soap:address location="http://aws.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**hay que cambiar el link http por https** (location="**http**://aws.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4" debería ser location="**https**://aws.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4")

Answer (score 0):

Para los que usan **CentOS 8** hay que editar el nivel de seguridad del `openssl` con:

```
sudo vim /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config
```

Al menos en mi caso bastó con cambiar `@SECLEVEL=2` por `@SECLEVEL=1`.